# How to send/receive data to/from server from swing java application using MQTT

Tags: java, mqtt

I think its very basic question but I need help in it to get started from somewhere.
I develop an application in java swing using netbeans IDE. I want to send data to another program (developed in python) residing on remote server for some operations over the data. So, I have to publish a topic, remote server will take it and send back the results. So, from where to start? Any basic example done by any other user (I did  some research but found irrelevant questions).

Comment: Do you have an MQTT broker already? Please show what research you've done so that we won't send you to it again

Comment: Yes, I already have MQTT broker. That broker is working with other applications. It takes inputs and publish results.  I want to integrate it with java application. For research regarding this, I found some examples and also came to know that there is library by the name Paho.

Comment: https://www.ev3dev.org/docs/tutorials/sending-and-receiving-messages-with-mqtt/. this is good example, but its in python.

Comment: Asking for examples is off topic for Stack Overflow, you need to try and when you get stuck ask a specific question about what you are stuck with. At the moment this question is too broad

Comment: Yes, I understand, I am going to edit the question. I need sometime to try some experiments. Thank you.